# Stop Ollydbg execution (breakpoint) when entering a specific module?

Tags: breakpoints, ollydbg

I have an EXE file in OllyDbg that uses a DLL. I've found an option to stop the EXE execution when the DLL loads, but I would now like to put a breakpoint everytime the execution enters the DLL module.

I thought about puttin a breakpoint on *every* `RETN` (and maybe `CALL`) instruction of that module, but it will be a huge pain... **So what's the way to pause execution every time it enters a specific module** (like xxx.dll) ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this when your execution break (stoped EXE execution when the DLL loads),

1. Alt-E (This will show you list of all loaded dlls).
2. Do right click on dll (you want to break into) then click on "view names".
3. New window will open which contain names of functions that are imported and exported by this dll, Sort the "type" column, press F2 (breakpoint) on all "export" types name.

now your execution will break on every time any exported function is called.
Hope this will solve your problem.

Although this can be automate using OllyDbg scripts if you need this frequently.